# zingchart scale-x items tooltip

Tags: zingchart

Using Zingchart, I want to show scale-x label in it's tooltip when hover on that item. Please see this demo. In this sample, instead of 'January 2016', I want to show 'January 2016', 'February 2016', 'March 2016' and etc.

According to this table
https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/zingchart-tokens/#tokens-list

I should use %scale-key-label but it does not work correctly on the scale tooltips.

Comment: Can you please explain how it's broken? Provide your chart configuration so other users can benefit from your question. [broken demo here](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/KVH6EKZX)

Comment: @nardecky Thanks. edited.